# Como puedo mostrar en tiempo real imagenes en Post en rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy usando json.jbuilder

```
json.array!(@posts) do |post|
  json.extract! post, :id, :body, :user_id
  json.image post.image.url
  json.url post_url(post, format: :json)
end
```

Y hago render con js

```
$("#posts").prepend("<%= j render @post %>")
```

Esta es la vista del render

```
    .col.s12.m6.l6
  -if post.image.blank?
    .card
      .card-content
        .text-left
          = post.user.email

      .text-left.card-content=post.body
  -elsif post.body.blank?
    .card
      .card-content
        .text-left
          =post.user.email
      .card-image
        =image_tag post.image.url, class: "materialboxed"
  -else
    .card
      .card-content
        .text-left
          =post.user.email

      .card-image
        =image_tag post.image.url, class: "materialboxed"
      .text-left.card-content
        %span= post.body
```

Y lo imprimo en una etiqueta

```
#posts
```

Quiero que muestre las imagenes pero no me las muestra, pero si pongo solo texto si lo muestra en tiempo real.